Why I find Feldman-Hajek so counterintuitive?
I just can not understand the following corollary of Feldman-Hajek(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldman%E2%80%93H%C3%A1jek_theorem):
If $\mu = N(0, C_\mu)$ and $\nu = N(0, C_\nu)$ are two infinite dimensional Gaussian measure, and $C_\mu = s C_\nu$, where $s$ not equal to $1$. then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular to each other.
How could this be? I mean if we sample from $\psi \sim \mu$,  then a sample from $\nu$ can be obtained by letting $\phi = s^{1/2}\psi$. How could $\mu$ and $\nu$ be singular to each other??

I don't see what singularity has to do with being able to obtain a sample from one distribution frmo a sample from the other.
